# Криптография на VHDL

Tags: железо

Подскажите где модно найти пример какого-либо криптографического алгоритма на языке VHDL для среды ISE?

Наверняка уже есть готовые проекты, с открытым кодом, но мне ни один поисковик ничего не выдал.

Comment: Странно, opencores.org в голову не приходил?

Comment: Там совсем ничего